# PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]:

Tags: php, sql, class

I want to querying with using this class:

```
class DB {
private static $_instance = null;   
private $_pdo,
        $_query,
        $_error = false,
        $_results,
        $_count = 0;

private function __construct() {
    try {
        $this->_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . Config::get('mysql/host') . ';dbname=' . Config::get('mysql/db'), Config::get('mysql/username'), Config::get('mysql/password'));          
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}

public static function getInstance() {
    if(!isset(self::$_instance)) {
        self::$_instance = new DB();
    }
    return self::$_instance;
}

public function query($sql, $params = array()) {
    $this->_error = false;
    if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)) {
        $x = 1;
        if(count($params)) {
            foreach ($params as $param) {
                $this->_query->bindValue($x, $param);
                $x++;
            }
        }

        if($this->_query->execute()) {
            $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();
        }else {
            $this->_error = true;
        }           
    } 
    return $this;
}
```

I am trying to reach query method like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM name 
                    WHERE namel LIKE :seek";
            $db = DB::getInstance();
            $db->query($sql, array(':seek' => $seek));
```

And I get this warning:
Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\blabla\classes\DB.php on line 36

I even don't sure that my way for reaching DB class.

Comment: Might be a silly question but why are you trying to make it so complicated?

Comment: I would be greatful if you tell me the simple way.

Comment: Just use PDO normally? I'm not sure you need to create your own class for handling it.

Comment: I used to but have seen this class from phpacademy on youtube and I supposed it is better way to making query, insert, delete and update doesn't it?

Comment: I'd just use PDO naturally. It's great out of the box. If you need clarification have a look at this resource. http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html

Comment: Every time I see the words *phpacademy* and *youtube*, I die a little inside. I have yet to see **anything** decent come out of that channel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update to your query fn() - issue was in your bindValue you need to pass param and value to bind

```
 public function query($sql, $params = array()) {
     $this->_error = false;
     if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)) {

         if(count($params)) {
             foreach ($params as $param => $value) {
                 $this->_query->bindValue($param, $value);                               
             }
         }

         if($this->_query->execute()) {
             $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
             $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();
         }else {
             $this->_error = true;
         }           
     } 
     return $this;
 }
```

Well it depends on your Like result, if you want it to display beginning and after you would have to update your value like so:

```
$this->_query->bindValue($param, '%' . $value . '%');
```

I don't know why you are returning $this.

Also if you are trying to get the result from outside the class, it needs to be public to access it.

```
public $_results;
```

Comment: Warning has gone but this time I get a white page(Page is loading but there is no db result.).

Comment: How do you want the like to search the current example is = but you can add in your percentage items to display part of the value? Also you are returning the object not the result if you want to return the result return $this->_results;

Comment: But you are not getting $db->_results because it is private when needs to be public.